# What does ^5 (caret + number) mean?

Tags: raku

Using ^5, one can get the first five elements of an array:

```
my @foo = 10..20;
say @foo[^5].join(',');
```

> 10,11,12,13,14

What is ^5 actually? Indexing syntax, a shortcut for lists, ... ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The prefix ^ operator is the [`upto`](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#prefix_%5E) operator. It generates a [`Range`](https://docs.perl6.org/type/Range) from 0 upto N (exclusive)

See also [prefix:<^>](https://docs.perl6.org/language/operators#prefix_%5E).

In the example it is used as a specification of an array slice, so it is equivalent to `@foo[0,1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: Technically it's short for `0..^5`